# can't load iap products in local, it waits forever

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm using the official in_app_purchase plugin, version ^1.0.4, and I'm following the official guide from Google insert my first iap (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0).

My consumable iap product is active on Play console with name "pacchetto_25", I've already submitted to the alpha channel my app and is accepted, the tester email is correctly configured in the Tester Group and in Licence Testing.

Now I'm trying to load the iap products in my app, the code is the same of the guide:

```
Future<void> loadPurchases() async {
  final available = await _iap.isAvailable();
  if (!available) {
        print("STORE NOT AVAILABLE");
        return;
      } else {
        print("STORE AVAILABLE");

        const ids = <String>{
          "pacchetto_25",
        };

        final response = await _iap.queryProductDetails(ids);

        response.notFoundIDs.forEach((element) {
          print('Purchase $element not found');
        });

        response.productDetails.forEach((element) {
          print("Purchase $element found");
        });

        // products =
        //     response.productDetails.map((e) => PurchasableProduct(e)).toList();
      }
 }
```

In my console I have the "STORE AVAILABLE" message, but then nothing else. If I put same debug point it does not stops on them, this problem appear after this line:

```
  final response = await _iap.queryProductDetails(ids);
```

Do someone know what's happening? I've no errors in my console and the code after loadPurchases() is not executed, it's like is waiting forever... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! If you have the same issue **DON'T** put

```
implementation("com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0")
```

in your build.gradle